# Update in the same table with an inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

My actual (and broken) query is this:

```
UPDATE t_1 SET b=(SELECT b FROM t_1 WHERE a=1)  WHERE b=1
```

How can I do it using a inner join?

Comment: I totally do not understand what you want. Can you add a example of how your rows should look like before and after?

Comment: `and broken`, why is it broken?

Comment: @Dorus a=1 and b=1 must have always the same number, it's very hard to explain why. It's broken because you can't do a subquery of the same table...

Comment: Something like `UPDATE t_1 SET b=(SELECT TOP 1 t_2.b from t_1 as t_2 WHERE t_2.a=t_1.b)`? (That probably still wont work, but it gives the idea)

Comment: @Dorus look the Tim3880's answer...

Comment: I suggest you stick with what works and worry about performance when it's actually too slow, not when you think it might be slow.

Comment: @Dorus thanks, but I am absolutely sure that I can do it with inner join, but I don't know how...

Comment: 1. You should have shown us the working version and asked one with a inner join. 2. I like to see a benchmark between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cheat MySQL on this:

```
UPDATE t_1 
SET b=(SELECT b FROM (select * from t_1) t WHERE a=1)  
WHERE b=1
```

A join version:

```
update t_1
join (select * from t_1) t
on t.a = 1 and t_1.b=1
set t_1.b= t.b;
```

Where is your source proving that all sub queries are slower than joins?

Comment: Thanks, it's true, but I want to use a inner join because they are faster than subqueries...

Comment: @Alexander Not true - _some_ subqueries may be slower, but it depends entirely on how the compiler develops the plan.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* do it this way:

```
UPDATE t_1 
SET t1.b=t2.b
FROM T_1 t1
INNER JOIN T_1 t2
  ON t2.a=1
WHERE b=1
```

So if that's more readable for you then go for it.